# Wordpress Multisite Cloning

Tags: wordpress, multisite

This is turning out to be an absolute nightmare.

I need to COPY / DUPLICATE the entire WP Multisite network and copy it onto additional domain.

I don't need to clone just one site of the MU. I need to clone the entire network with its setup, plugins etc.

I used to use the Duplicator plugin for the single WP installations and though that MU will be quite similar, but not at all.

Is there a way to do this ?

I just can't find any specific information on this, please help.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite ... As you saw, Duplicator is not intended for (nor does it support) multisite migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the wordpress from one domain to another domain is not simple, because there are serveral records in several tables stores the domain name in serialized format,

Let's assume, you have and `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com`.

- Create a backup of your database (dump)
- Copy all files to your `newdomain.com` document root.
- Import your database dump to the new database (if you have)
- If you have new database too, change the `wp-config.php` database section with the credentials.
- Download [enter link description here](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) this tool, and copy it into a wp_replace directory
- Go you http://newdomain.com/wp_replace/
- Run this script, and change `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`. **Warning: at here do not enter http:// and trailing slash!**
- Go to your dashboard, go to options / permalinks, and refresh.
- Delete that `wp_replace` directory

Comment: The OP is moving a multi-site...

Comment: and what is the problem with that? This tool can be used for multisite too: http://forum.yourwebapp.mobi/moving-wordpress-moving-a-multisite-network/

Comment: hey, many thanks for your help. Quick question, let's say I have the root domain which olddomain.com and a subsite that is a part of my network - olddomain.com/subsite/ .. How do I go about the subsite ?

Comment: You do not need to care about this. This script is only change `olddomain.com` strings to `newdomain.com`, so your new string will be `newdomain.com/subsite/` Read that manual on your link what I commented.

Comment: Ok, i'm on it .. will report back soon .. many thanks